# Difference between XeTeX and LuaTeX

Tags: latex, pdftex, xetex

I have a hard time contrasting XeTeX and LuaTeX.

At the moment, I am using XeTeX almost exclusively, mainly because it uses UTF-8 as the native input encoding and because it supports TTF and OTF fonts.

*However, the lack of support for pdftex’ microtyping is mildly annoying.*

LuaTeX, on the other hand, does support this, as well as UTF-8 input and (rudimentary?) fontspec support.

So my question boils down to: **Is there any advantage in using XeTeX over using LuaTeX?** Has anybody used both and can compare them? In particular, LuaTeX sounds very experimental and unstable – but is this really the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From February?  Been a while since I looked for latex qns here on SU, obviously...

Speed (Luatex can be kind of slow), older code base, and ease of use (You don't need to *do* anything with Xetex to use system fonts).  I don't know of any feature advantage Xetex has over Luatex.

Comment: And there I was aiming for the tumbleweed badge. ;-) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Xetex microtypography: from [the Texlive 2010 pretest page](http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html):

```
XeTeX now supports margin kerning along the same lines as pdfTeX
```

So Xetex is a moving target.

Comment: Wow, great news. However, the restriction of `\write18` – not so great, if I understand that correctly.